# make multi-condition for query in querysolution this query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
(Border <= 10 AND Border2 >= 100) OR (Border <= 200 AND Border2 >= 500)
```

But, i'd like to take values of left and right border from query
I try to explain 
make multi-condition for query in query

```
SELECT TOP 1 Border, Border2 FROM table2 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: From which tables? which sample data?

Comment: but like to take values

Comment: I try to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those values, then don't select all columns with *, instead select only the columns you want:

```sql
SELECT leftBorder, rightBorder FROM...
```

Comment: like to take values